# Eclipse CDT - how to add include path to multiple projects non-manually

Tags: c++, eclipse, automation

I'm working on a code base that has about 50 Eclipse C++ projects (`.cproject`) as part of a single "executable".
To make indexing and type-resolution work, I have to add other directories to a given project's properties: `Right-click > properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes`

This is ok if I just have to do this once or twice but . . . there are some directories that need to be added to **all** my projects.

**QUESTION**

Is there a **safe** and automated way to add an include directory to all my projects?
I'm sure I could modify the `.project` file but I'm hoping there's a way to script `add directory X to the include directories of project Y`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `Window > Preferences` - there's no place for me to add **include dirs**. That `Paths and Symbols` entry only appears for `Right-click > Properties` on a project. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it, there's no `C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes`, sorry that was just a wild guess.